# Why my angularJS doesn't work on my sample web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I try to learn AngularJs and do some codes but when I run it on my Browser (Chrome/IE) the javavscript codes doesn't work. The "{{product.like}}" code thing is not working. There's anything or dependencies that I have to install or what? I appreciate all helps and answers. Sorry for my ENG. :)

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
    <title>InstantGram | Posts</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif/png" href="icon.png">
</head>
<header>
    <h1 class = "mainHead"><span id = "insColor">Instant</span>Gram</h1>
</header>
<body ng-app = "myApp">
    <div class ="main" ng-controller = "mainController">
        <div>
    <h2 class = "sunset">The Unusual Sunset</h2>
    <img src = "The_sunset.jpg" alt="Unloaded Image" width="477px"                     
height="268px"/>
    <div class="rating">
            <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+ {{ product.likes }}     </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
    <h2>The Metropolis Before 1927</h2>
    <img src = "metropolis_before.jpg" alt = "Unloaded Image"/>
    <div class="rating">
            <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+ {{ product.likes }}     </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
    <h2>The Paradise</h2>
    <img src = "lake.jpg" alt = "unloaded image" width="477px" height="268px">
    <div class="rating">
            <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+ {{ product.likes }}     </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
              <h2>Available for iPhone and Android.</h2>
              <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecade-content/projects/shutterbugg/app-store.png" width="120px" />
              <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/google-play.png" width="110px" />
            </div>
          </div>    
          <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ANGULARJS/JAVASCRIPT CODES:**

***- App.js***

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

***-mainController.js***

```
  app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.like =  0;
    $scope.plusOne = function(index) { 
      $scope.like[index].likes += 1; 
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I see <script> tags to load app.js and mainController.js, but is there one to load angular.js itself?

Answer (score 1):

You are not including AngularJS in your application. You could, as you say install it, and I would recommend that, but you still need to reference it. Here is your original code running in a stack snippet that included AngularJS at the top.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  window.app = angular.module("myApp", []);
}());

(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.like = 0;
    $scope.plusOne = function(index) {
      $scope.like[index].likes += 1;
    };
  }]);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <header>
    <h1 class="mainHead"><span id="insColor">Instant</span>Gram</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="main" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div>
      <h2 class="sunset">The Unusual Sunset</h2>
      <img src="The_sunset.jpg" alt="Unloaded Image" width="477px" height="268px" />
      <div class="rating">
        <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+ {{ product.likes }} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <h2>The Metropolis Before 1927</h2>
      <img src="metropolis_before.jpg" alt="Unloaded Image" />
      <div class="rating">
        <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+ {{ product.likes }} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <h2>The Paradise</h2>
      <img src="lake.jpg" alt="unloaded image" width="477px" height="268px">
      <div class="rating">
        <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+ {{ product.likes }} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Available for iPhone and Android.</h2>
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecade-content/projects/shutterbugg/app-store.png" width="120px" />
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/google-play.png" width="110px" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Note I collapsed your scripts modules and controllers scripts into one for the purposes of the demonstration above but the point is that you need to load AngularJS, or any other script that you depend on, before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your  tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading

Answer (score 0):

Select a version and Download the js file from https://angularjs.org and then add it under head tag. Main problem here is that you must put script under

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
<title>InstantGram | Posts</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif/png" href="icon.png">
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
</head>
```